# Setting up PostgreSQL driver (PQSQL) for use with PySide

Tags: python, qt, postgresql, pyside

I have been using psycopg2 with Python so far to connect to PostgreSQL and I have been trying for some time to use QtSql instead of psycopg2 without any success.

I have Windows 7 64-bits installed. I have python 3.3 installed at C:\python33 (through the installer) and PySide 1.2.1 installed (through the installer) and PostgreSQL 9.3.1 installed at C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\ (through EntrepriseDB installer). I have also installed QT5 hoping to solve the problem in vain at C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1 (through the installer).

In despair I have tried to follow the instructions [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qpsql) even though I'm not sure they apply for PySide (I think they apply for QT only) and failed to do so because I couldn't find the command "nmake" anywhere.

I need to install the PostgreSQL driver (PQSQL) for ***PySide*** but I have failed to do so. I need simple instructions on how to do so.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: When I do db=QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL") it says :
QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
and the reason for that is that I didn't manage to install the driver so far. All I have done is merely copying various files from various folders from QT and PostgreSQL and trying to put them in PySide directory without any success. I have also tried to follow the instructions on the website I linked to but couldn't find "nmake" command.

Comment: As I already mentioned, I'm using Windows 7 64-bits.